# Unlimited Properties in sql table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a user table with 60 columns .Client is looking for more properties .so we are thinking of implementing support for Dynamic columns .

More on Domain : -Its a email campaign we store the users with their properties .the client send us big excel file from their crm (sometimes more than 100 column) but we have only 60 column so we upload only 60 column chose by client into our system . then client set business logic in a UI (like which users will recieve mails all based on properties).then we sent mails matching the properties .clients are asking for more properties now .

i can think of two solutions

1) A child table which will save the rows as columns

-- a huge impact on existing system and for reporting converting the rows into column will be very diffcult .

2)XML property :- though it is easy to implement on both DB and object layer .
     performance could be of major concern since searching with in xml with joins using xml properties will be costly one.

Is there another way or which is better in above two .i can't go for strtuctured Db (like mangoDb or Big table) ? thanks in advance

Comment: Could you describe the domain more? Are the new columns fixed? Are they filled for every customer. In ideal it would be nice to see them

Comment: Do you need to search on the new columns? If not, then XML or [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) are possible.

Comment: Normalize your table. 60 columns in a table is not natural, and usually can be split to sub-tables

Comment: More on Domain : -Its a email campaign we store the users with their properties .the client send us big excel file from their crm (sometimes more than 100 column) but we have only 60 column so we upload only 60 column chose by client into our system . then client set business logic in a UI (like which users will recieve mails all based on properties).then we sent mails matching the properties .clients are asking for more properties now .

Comment: How the normalization will handle the umlimited properties situation ?

Comment: we have reports based on these properties.so searching can't be neglected.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered re-structuring/normalizing the tables? 60 col in a table?? I would have my concerns then here! If this is unavoidable then using an XML based approach with LINQ to XML for searching is what I would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Split your table into multiple tables, then you can combine the original format of the table into a view. you view can then be use instead of that table for "legacy" code that wants that data in the particular format.